# Jupyter-notebook does not show my desktop folders

Tags: jupyter-notebook

when I launch jupyter notebook, I select desktop Folder, it says the folder is empty. I have many folders on desktop but jupyter notebook does not show any of them. Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Are you running on Windows 10?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using windows 10

Comment: Check paths of folders in the desktop. Because sometimes there are two desktop folders in Onedrive and in the user directory. It might be the case that you are accessing user desktop with the notebook but the folders inside desktop are in overdrive.

Comment: are you able to see other folders?

Answer (score 7):

I was experiencing the same issue as I could not access both desktop and documents on jupyter notebooks because on jupyter notebook it was showing that these folders are empty and I was very frustrated lol. It could be the folders are auto backed up on OneDrive, so on jupyter notebook, access them through onedrive i.e. onedrive>desktop or any other folders such as documents. I accessed them through onedrive. I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 4):

Hey Hey I was facing the same error, I tried downgrading upgrading re-installation but no results came out finally after two days efforts I found that Jupiter need to be started in a user directory by using(cmd)

```
cd C:\Users\Hamza Wahla
```

Then type

```
jupyter notebook
```

[check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvuSr.png)

Comment: Thanks! That's the solution for me!

Comment: Your welcome

You can ping me for any Pythonic help.

www.linkedin.com/in/mhwahla

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue on windows 10; there are two Desktop folders!

one directly under `/` and another one under `/OneDrive`

The one you want is `/OneDrive/Desktop`

Comment: This is also suggested by [Yograj Singh Mandloi in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55200858/jupyter-notebook-does-not-show-my-desktop-folders#comment97172889_55200858). While comments aren't Answers, I believe you should still give attribution.

Answer (score 0):

Well I didn't find a way to make this default. But I am able to open the location whichever I want.
When you run "jupyter notebook" from your terminal. It was mentioning the serving location as "/Users/username/Downloads"
so to set another directory as working directory, just write

```
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/Users/username/Desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

So this could happen because of few reasons:

1. OneDrive: As mentioned in other replies, folders are backed up on OneDrive and kept under the same folder for user.
2. The files are hidden in the user folder. Check the properties of the user folder and the hidden checkbox should be unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me, Jupiter Notebook was not able to recognize my documents, though i had files on my documents folder it was still showing empty, that's because my documents were saved in one drive, the solution is simple, open one drive in Jupiter and access documents and you'll find all your files there.